# Set the same modal window for update and add

Tags: php, jquery, html

I have created a modal window for updating records fetched from database, Now I want the same modal window for adding new records too, I don't want to write the same form code for adding purpose (code reusesability), but how do I change the `<legend>Update record</legend>`to`<legend>Add record</legend>` dynamically.

```
<div id="modal">

        <div id="update">

            <span class="closeBttn">X</span>

            <form action="" method="post">

                <fieldset>

                    <legend>Update Record</legend>

                    <p>
                        <label for="name">Name: </label><br />
                        <input type="text" id="name" name="name" />
                    </p>

                    <p>
                        <label for="subject">Subject: </label><br />
                        <input type="text" id="subject" name="subject" />
                    </p>

                    <p>
                        <label for="theory">Theory: </label><br />
                        <input type="text" id="theory" name="theory" />
                    </p>

                    <p>
                        <label for="practical">Practical: </label><br />
                        <input type="text" id="practical" name="practical" />
                    </p>

                    <p>
                        <input type="hidden" name="id" id="id" />
                        <input type="hidden" name="action" value="update" />
                        <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Update" />
                    </p>

                </fieldset>

            </form>


        </div>


    </div>
```

Comment: Please add your jQuery or PHP  code for more clarification.

Comment: you use a bit of javascript, show yours and maybe someone will add the line of code required for you

Comment: @GovindSamrow I used jquery..but which part of the source file should i paste here...its a lengthy one....can you not explain it here using simple javascript or tell me the procedure

Comment: @RiggsFolly I used jquery..but which part of the source file should i paste here...its a lengthy one....can you not explain it here using simple javascript or tell me the procedure

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
$(function(){
    var id = $('#id').val();
    if(id > 0)
    {
        $("#modal legend").text("Update Record");
    }else{
        $("#modal legend").text("Update Record");
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it simply using PHP also... see below code

```
<?php
if(!empty($_REQUEST['id']))//fetching from url
{
    echo '<legend>Update Record</legend>';
}
else
{
    echo '<legend>Add Record</legend>';
}
?>
```